# Android Sockets between devices

Tags: android, sockets, networking, client-server, chat

I've trying to connect 2 devices by sockets, but it never works. One of the devices is the Server that save the configuration (IP and port where listen) on a database, then the other device,the Client , connect with the database and take the configuration to conect.

Database querys and echos works fine (PHP) but the method wich open the client socket doesn't work, it run out of time to connect and throws an exception. I dont know if  the ServerSocket doesn't receive the petition or the ClientSocket doesn't send it...

The code below: (bit bad, but is for test).

Server code:

```
public class Server{

private int puerto = 4567;

private ServerSocket serverSocket;


public void conectar() {

    try {

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(puerto);

        while (true) {

            Log.i("SocketServer", "escuchando");

            Socket cliente = serverSocket.accept(); 

            Log.i("Socket","Cliente ha conectado"); 

            BufferedReader ent = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    cliente.getInputStream())); 


            String linea = ent.readLine(); 

            Log.i("Cliente", "Cliente envia=" + linea);

            cliente.close(); 

            Log.i("Servidor","Cliente desconectado");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.e("Error", "Error en el servidor");

    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public class Cliente {

private int puerto;

private InetAddress direccion;

public Cliente(int puerto, InetAddress direccion){

    this.puerto = puerto;

    this.direccion = direccion;

}

public void conectar(){

    try{

    Socket cliente = new Socket(direccion, puerto);

    Log.i("Cliente", "Conectado");

    conectado = true;

    PrintWriter salida=new PrintWriter(cliente.getOutputStream(),true);

    salida.println("Hola, soy el cliente");

    Log.i("Cliente", "Mensaje enviado");

    cliente.close();

    }catch(SocketException e){

        Log.e("ErrorSocket","Error al abrir socket " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.e("ErrorSocket","Error al enviar " + e.getMessage());

    }


}
```

}

I get the InetAddress by method below:

```
//The String result param is like: "192.168.0.1&23456"

public InetAddress getInetAddress(String result) {

    InetAddress address = null;

    //5 it an example
    if (result.length() > 5 && result != null) {

        try {

            String[] data = result.split("&");

            Log.i("Data", data[0] + " " + data[1]);

            puerto = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);

            Log.i("PUERTO", "Puerto:" + puerto);

            String ip = data[0];

            Log.i("IP", ip);

            String[] str = ip.split("\\.");

            byte[] IP = new byte[str.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

                IP[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
            }

            address = InetAddress.getByAddress(IP);

            Log.i("InetAddress",address.getCanonicalHostName());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Error", "Error al conseguir InnetAddress");

        }

    } else {

        Log.e("Error", "String capturado vacio");

        return address;
    }

    return address;

}
```

Thanks :)
It a test project for my College Final Project, a GPS-Chat.

EDIT: 3G nat breaks this way to develop an android connection between 2 devices by sockets. I'll study the way to do it with GCM and another server.

Answer (score 0):

For your client code I find that this works really well for me:

```
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(cliente.getOutputStream());
```

Then to send data use:

```
wr.write("DATA TO SEND");
wr.flush();
```

It looks like you have good logging going on, I would also add Log output lines to see if it got past the socket and have it print out all of the data that you get. If all of the logs show the correct data but the client just won't connect, try the code I posted above, I haven't had problems with it.

Comment: Thanks man but... It doesn't work, the client never connects. Maybe it's the way I'm debugging it. I try with 2 real devices, 1 real and the emulator... but nothing (and yes! i'm giving Internet, network... permissions.

I dont know what else do, I even try this code: http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesgeneralprogramming/262-socket-programming-in-android-applications

And others... Something easy in the computers but it breaks me down in Android.

Answer (score 0):

## ServerApplication.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class ServerApp {
ArrayList clientOutputStreams;
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable{
BufferedReader reader;
Socket sock;
public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket){

try {
sock=clientSocket;
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
reader=new BufferedReader(isr);
} catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
@Override
 public void run() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
String message;
try {
while((message=reader.readLine())!=null)
{
System.out.println("read :"+message);
tellEveryone(message);
 }
  } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
    private void tellEveryone(String message) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Iterator itr=clientOutputStreams.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext()){
 PrintWriter pWriter=(PrintWriter)itr.next();
 pWriter.println(message);
 pWriter.flush();
  }
  }

  }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new ServerApp().createSocket();
  }
   private void createSocket() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   clientOutputStreams=new ArrayList();
   try {
ServerSocket socket=new ServerSocket(5000);
while(true){
Socket clientSocket=socket.accept();
PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
clientOutputStreams.add(writer);
Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
t.start();
System.out.println("Got a Connection to the Client");
 } 
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

}



 Chat Client Source Code
 ===================================================
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;


public class ChatClient {
JTextField outgoing;
JTextArea incoming;
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
Socket sock;
public void layOutDesign(){
JFrame frame= new JFrame("Simple Chat Client");
JPanel mainPanel= new JPanel();
 incoming= new JTextArea(15,25);
incoming.setLineWrap(true);
incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
incoming.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane qScroller=new JScrollPane(incoming);
qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
outgoing=new JTextField(20);
JButton sendButton=new JButton("Send");
sendButton.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());
mainPanel.add(qScroller);
mainPanel.add(outgoing);
mainPanel.add(sendButton);
setupNetworking();
Thread readerThread=new Thread(new IncomingReader());
readerThread.start();
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
frame.setSize(400, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
private void setupNetworking() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
 sock=new Socket("10.30.10.156", 5000);
 InputStreamReader isR=new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
 reader=new BufferedReader(isR);
 writer=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
  System.out.println("Network Established.");
 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
 public class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener{

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 try{
 writer.println(outgoing.getText());
 writer.flush();
 }catch (Exception e1) {
  // TODO: handle exception
  e1.printStackTrace();
  }

  outgoing.setText("");
  outgoing.requestFocus();
 }

 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  new ChatClient().layOutDesign();
  }
 public class IncomingReader implements Runnable{

  String message;
  @Override
   public void run() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {
  while((message=reader.readLine())!=null){
  System.out.println("Read :"+message);
   incoming.append(message+"\n");
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }

  }
  }
```

Go to server code...
and change the IP of your System
then connect to the Clients

And enjoy the Chatting between your colleagues in your Network....

Answer (score 0):

Better option for exchange information about GPS position is use websocket. I very simple server for this kind of application https://github.com/yoman07/geo_server demo class for android you can find here https://github.com/yoman07/PhotoShoter/blob/master/PhotoShoterModule/src/main/java/com/photoshoter/SocketClient.java .